# Unable to find files which have been in the folder one minute in Mac's Zsh

Tags: macos, find, zsh, rm

I need to find files which have been in the folder Wastebasket exactly one minute.
The files have been moved all over my computer to the folder.

I run the following unsuccessfully

```
find -atime n1m .
```

I get all my files in the directory by the command, even ones which I just created.
It seems that the option -atime is not correct.

**How can you find files which access time is one minute?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

`find -amin 1`

`n` is just a variable that you replace with a number.

`+n` eg `+1` means greater
`n` eg `1` means exactly
`-n` eg `-1` means less than

Comment: @Lou: Thank you for your answer! Your command works well in my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `n`. The `n` in the manpage stands for a number.

```
find -atime 1m .
```

Comment: @Chris: Your command should work. However, I did not manage to get it work by touching a file and then running your command.

Comment: From the man: File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out how many  24-hour  periods  ago  the  file  was  last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

'fractional part is ignored'

I think that might be why

Comment: @Lou - That is only if no units are specified. '1m' is different from '1'. The 'm' specifies minutes as the unit, so it checks 1 minute. From the man: If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last access time and the time find was started is exactly n units.

Comment: Yea I saw the m notation and usually use it in practice but never read the man that in depth. +1 for teaching me something

Answer (score 2):

Since you've mentioned you're using zsh, I might as well suggest a zsh-specific answer. To find all files with access time of minute or less ago, you can use the command:

```
$> ls *(.am-1)
```

Comment: @sykora: Where can you get the documentation for such great commands? I did not find your parameters at $man find in my Z shell.

Comment: This particular command I lifted in part from the zsh reference card: http://www.bash2zsh.com/zsh_refcard/refcard.pdf . You can also search the zsh wiki, the zshlovers man page, and the other man pages. And google, of course.